# Как переопределить стиль Clearfix?

Tags: css

Есть тег `<div class="cupons clearfix">`

```
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {
    content: "\0020";
    display: block;
    height: 0px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}
.clearfix {
    zoom: 1;
}
```

Как отменить действие clearfix? Не получилось,делал вот так

```
.cupons {
    background: orange;
    clear: none!important;
    float: left;
}
.cupons::before {
    content: none!important;
    display: none;
}
.cupons::after {
    content: none!important;
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

А вообще достаточно .cupons определить после .clearfix (ниже в коде css), zoom: 1 - лучше вынести в условные комментарии для старых IE, !important лучше без очень большой необходимости не использовать.

```
.cupons.clearfix {
    background: orange;
    clear: none;
    float: left;
}
.cupons.clearfix::before {
    content: none;
    display: none;
}
.cupons.clearfix::after {
    content: none;
    display: none;
}
```